# cannot read property "names" of undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coffeescript, jsx

I'm writing reactjs (coffescript+JSX syntax). If user writes something into input and then  clicks on the button, get ajax request is sent and the result in callback function (json object) isn't inserted into the state **names** using setState and I get following error: **cannot read property "names" of undefined**

I don't know where should be a problem

```
$ ->
# first component
 MainComponent = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
   names:[]

  _getSpecificCard: (card_name) ->
   $.get "home/users/#{card_name}", (newuser) -> @setState names:@state.names.concat([newuser])                                               

  _getAllcards: ->
   @state.names.map((user) ->
    <Card key={user.id} name={user.login} avatarurl={user.avatar_url}  />)

  render: ->
   cards= @_getAllcards
   <div>
    <SimpleForm addCard={@_getSpecificCard} />
     {cards}
   </div>

# second component
 SimpleForm= React.createClass

  _handleSubmit: (e) ->
   e.preventDefault()
   textInput= @refs.login
   @props.addCard(textInput.value)

  render: ->
   <form onSubmit={@_handleSubmit}>
    <input placeholder="github login" ref="login" />
    <button>Show user</button>
   </form>

# third component
 Card = React.createClass
  render: ->
   <div>
    <h3>{@props.name}</h3>
     <img src={@props.avatarurl} width=80 />
   </div>

 ReactDOM.render(<MainComponent />,document.getElementById("pluralsight"))
```

// compiled version

```
$(function() {
  var Card, MainComponent, SimpleForm;
  MainComponent = React.createClass({displayName: "MainComponent",
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        names: []
      };
    },
    _getSpecificCard: function(card_name) {
      return $.get("home/users/" + card_name, function(newuser) {
        return this.setState({
          names: this.state.names.concat([newuser])
        });
      });
    },
    _getAllcards: function() {
      return this.state.names.map(function(user) {
        return React.createElement(Card, {
          "key": user.id,
          "name": user.login,
          "avatarurl": user.avatar_url
        });
      });
    },
    render: function() {
      var cards;
      cards = this._getAllcards;
      return React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement(SimpleForm, {
        "addCard": this._getSpecificCard
      }), cards);
    }
  });
  SimpleForm = React.createClass({displayName: "SimpleForm",
    _handleSubmit: function(e) {
      var textInput;
      e.preventDefault();
      textInput = this.refs.login;
      return this.props.addCard(textInput.value);
    },
    render: function() {
      return React.createElement("form", {
        "onSubmit": this._handleSubmit
      }, React.createElement("input", {
        "placeholder": "github login",
        "ref": "login"
      }), React.createElement("button", null, "Show user"));
    }
  });
  Card = React.createClass({displayName: "Card",
    render: function() {
      return React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement("h3", null, this.props.name), React.createElement("img", {
        "src": this.props.avatarurl,
        "width": 80
      }));
    }
  });
  return ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MainComponent, null), document.getElementById("pluralsight"));
});
```

Comment: Any chance you could provide a preprocessed version of your code? This would let us who are not very familiar with CoffeeScript help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that `this` refers to the component class in the callback, use `=>`:

```
$.get "home/users/#{card_name}", (newuser) => @setState names:@state.names.concat([newuser])
                                           ^
```

Otherwise, it is out of scope when the callback is executed.

Comment: You are right. I thought  it was problem with react  but not. I have to use this fat arrow. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `$.get` callback does not have your React component as it's `this` (or `@`) context. You can use the fat arrow `=>` to preserve the `@`:

```js
_getSpecificCard: (card_name) ->
  $.get "home/users/#{card_name}", (newuser) => self.setState names:self.state.names.concat([newuser])
```

You may also need to bind the function when you pass it to the child component to ensure the correct `this`:

```js
<SimpleForm addCard={@_getSpecificCard.bind(@)} />
```